# .sln file is not found in client website (folder) visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Client has given me a website in visual studio 2008 but solution file (.sln) is not there (missing).How can I create again solution .sln for all website.Is there possible to again solution create.

Comment: Do you have the csproj files? if so, I think that the best you can do is create an new solution, and add the existing projects into it. Other information like solution folders is probably lost, unfortunately.

Comment: No it is only website no project in it

Comment: why negative ask me a solution

Comment: Just a website? you mean no code? if so, you can't get it. Your client needs to give you the project. If you do have code, then you're in for dirty work. You'll need to re-create the project and add the existing code to it. In either way I would talk to the client. If there is a project file for other IDE (other than VS), it counts too, you should be able to convert it.

Comment: yes it is just a website not a project and code in it

Comment: all files like test.aspx.vb include in it

Comment: Well, simply put, there is missing information. Your options are to either re-create it, or request it from your client. The second option is what you should do imo, but if your client can't supply you what you need and you really wanna do this work, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx).

Comment: its a website not a project

Answer (score 1):

i think it is a web site not a web application open it as a website and select

File>Save as

it show you a dialog file to save it as a .sln file

Comment: How can I open it.No solution file in it

Comment: File>Open Website and on the opened dialog box select your root folder of your website

Comment: There are so many files in it like default.aspx,login.aspx.How can i include all files

Comment: there is no project in it

Comment: do not looking for some files like .prj or .sln just select this from file menu "file>open website" when open dialog box shows type the root path of your website at "Folder:" and select open

Answer (score 0):

You need to see [How to: Create a Project from Existing Code Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx).

To sum it up:

1. On the menu bar, choose File, New, Project From Existing Code.
2. In the wizard, specify details about the existing code files that will be added to the project, and about the app that you will build.

Comment: its a website not project

Answer (score 0):

To add a sln file to a Website project that does not have one using Visual Studio 2015 Release 2 simply open the project as a website.

File > Open > Web Site

Then click save and Visual Studio will add the .sln file. In the save dialog that opens, navigate to the directory containing the website project to have the .sln file saved with the project.

[image: Open Website Image]